# Android webview: controlling which browser is used on redirection

Tags: android, browser, webview

So I wanted when I use `window.location` in my webview, the page to be shown on the same page and to not open a new window with the default browser, so I added this code:

```
     view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that now every link that I use opens in the same window. What should I do if for example I want to use `window.open(url)` and I want this to be opened with the default browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
     view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null) {
                if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Long story short you override the method but checking if the url is local or not ("If it's not local it should start with "http://"). Of course you can customize it as you wish.